# Switching String or Multiple IF Statements

Tags: php, string, switch-statement, strcmp

I need to a perform an action based on the value of a `string`. I think that if I use a `switch` statement it will be slower than using multiple `if`s and `strcmp` function. Thoughts?

Method 1:

```
switch ( $string ){
   case 'Hello': //do stuff
       break;
   case 'Howdy': //do stuff
       break;
}
```

Method 2:

```
if ( strcmp($string, 'Hello') == 0 ) // do stuff
if ( strcmp($string, 'Howdy') == 0 ) // do stuff
```

Which one will be most effective?

Comment: `strcmp` is weird here. `$string === "Howdy"` is fine.

Comment: @Halcyon wouldn't `strcmp ` perform better than simply comparing strings? like `$string === "Howdy"`?

Comment: Probably not, `strcmp` is a function and `===` is a language construct. Calling a function is relatively slow. If you want to know for sure write a benchmark. My guess is that `strcmp` is easily 100x slower.

Comment: @Halcyon thanks for your reply. Also, I don't think this is a duplicate since the question is the performance value of the comparison in a `switch` versus `strcmp` and not a comparison between `switch/if`.

Comment: The accepted answer covers performance.